# How to add one element(not collection) to xml file by JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

In jaxb examples, which i have found in internet, if programmer want to add element to xml file, it makes by updating all collection. But i want to do this by updating/adding only one element from collection. How can i do this?

Comment: maybe give us source exemple.

Comment: @crashxxl http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JAXB/article.html here an example. As you can see string "m.marshal(bookstore, new File(BOOKSTORE_XML));" writes all collection, not one object. I think, if this collection will be very large, it will be not very good.